# Restrict user after several failed requests for several minutes in reactjs , Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to block the user after making many requests on the front-end side for a certain time (for example, ten minutes)? Like **throttle** in **django-rest-api**... but with **React JS**, let's do this in user input forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Throttling work in javascript you need to create a function like this:

```
function throttle(mainFunction, delay) {


let timerFlag = null; // Variable to keep track of the timer

  // Returning a throttled version 
  return (...args) => {
    if (timerFlag === null) { // If there is no timer currently running
      mainFunction(...args); // Execute the main function 
      timerFlag = setTimeout(() => { // Set a timer to clear the timerFlag after the specified delay
        timerFlag = null; // Clear the timerFlag to allow the main function to be executed again
      }, delay);
    }
  };
}
```

and then attach it to some kind of action for example button click, form change or on scroll event. In your case here is an example:

```
<input value={value} onChange={e => throttledUpdateData(e.target.value)}>
```

to read more you can see article [here](https://dev.to/jeetvora331/throttling-in-javascript-easiest-explanation-1081#:%7E:text=Throttling%20is%20a%20technique%20that,resizing%2C%20fetching%20data%2C%20etc.). Hope that helps.